# How to distinguish between biased and random distributions

Tags: random, statistics, cryptography, probability, cryptanalysis

Actually, I am working on cryptography and I have to distinguish a number generated from a true random number generator and a number from a biased number generator.
Is there any theorem to follow and know how many samples of data do we need to distinguish and how much the bias should be?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try NISt asses test...

Comment: Try Diehard tests, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests